# If $x_n = \frac{1}{nα_n}$ where $α_n$ is such that $2^{α_n−2} < n ≤ 2^{α_n−1}$, is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

For $n ≥ 1$, let $x_n = \frac{1}{nα_n}$
where $α_n$ is such that $2^{α_n−2} < n ≤ 2^{α_n−1}$. Is
the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ convergent?

Answer (score 1):

$$\alpha_n\lt\log_2n+2\implies x_n\gt\frac1{n(\log_2n+2)}\sim\frac{\log2}{n\log n}$$